# How many files are on my HFS drive?

Tags: hard-drive, unix

Is there a quick and easy way to tell about how many files I have on a given HFS+ formatted hard drive?

On Unix, I use `df -i`, but HFS+ apparently doesn't use inodes and returns a silly answer based on the percentage of disk space I'm using:

```
# df -i /Volumes/BARRY

Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s2   4.0T   2.7T   1.3T    68% 660707979 315962685   68%   /Volumes/BARRY
```

Of course, I can `find /Volumes/BARRY | wc` or something, but does HFS+ keep track of how many files are on a given filesystem?

Comment: Are you only talking about command lines in Terminal? If not, use Disk Utility is easy.

Comment: Brilliant, I should've thought of that. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. Just out of curiosity, is there a command-line way to do it? HFS+ obviously stores this information somewhere.

Comment: "diskutil info" does not provide this information, oddly enough.